# Azure autoscale odd behaviour

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an app service plan, which scales in the following way:

- Range: 2-20 instances
- CPU > 20%: scale to 20 instances
- CPU < 15%: scale to 2 instances

The actual number of instances that I see over time is the following:

- 20 instances
- (CPU ~ 0%)
- scale down to 2 instances
- (load started: CPU > 50%)
- up to 20 instances (in ~5 mins)
- (load finished: CPU ~ 0%)
- down to 15 instances (in ~5 mins)
- down to 12 instances (in ~5 mins)
- down to 5 instances (in ~5 mins)
- down to 2 instances (in ~5 mins)

How to make it scale to 2 instances instantly, without additional steps in-between?

Also, sometimes, the scale UP from 2 to 20 instances fails, and 2 instances remain at huge load. Is it possible to tell azure to scale to as many instances as possible, instead of leaving users with 2 instances during huge load?

Update: add scale settings JSON.

Update: add scale settings screenshots.

Overall scale settings:
[image: scale settings and chart]

How it scales up:
[image: scale up]

How it scales down:
[image: scale down]

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/autoscaleSettings",
  "location": "westus",
  "tags": {
    "$type": "...",
    "...": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "profiles": [
      {
        "name": "Default",
        "capacity": {
          "minimum": "2",
          "maximum": "20",
          "default": "2"
        },
        "rules": [
          {
            "metricTrigger": {
              "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
              "metricNamespace": "",
              "metricResourceUri": "...",
              "timeGrain": "PT1M",
              "statistic": "Average",
              "timeWindow": "PT5M",
              "timeAggregation": "Maximum",
              "operator": "GreaterThan",
              "threshold": 20
            },
            "scaleAction": {
              "direction": "Increase",
              "type": "ExactCount",
              "value": "20",
              "cooldown": "PT1M"
            }
          },
          {
            "metricTrigger": {
              "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
              "metricNamespace": "",
              "metricResourceUri": "...",
              "timeGrain": "PT1M",
              "statistic": "Average",
              "timeWindow": "PT5M",
              "timeAggregation": "Average",
              "operator": "LessThan",
              "threshold": 15
            },
            "scaleAction": {
              "direction": "Decrease",
              "type": "ExactCount",
              "value": "2",
              "cooldown": "PT1M"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "...",
    "targetResourceUri": "...",
    "notifications": [
      {
        "operation": "Scale",
        "email": {
          "sendToSubscriptionAdministrator": false,
          "sendToSubscriptionCoAdministrators": false,
          "customEmails": [
            "..."
          ]
        },
        "webhooks": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can custom the Autoscale settings of your Web Apps to achieve your requirement.

If you are using C#, you can leverage the [Azure Monitoring Services Management Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring). Otherwise, you also can implement with the REST APIs in your using language to manage the Autoscale settings. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510367.aspx for the detailed description of the elements of the settings.

Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md for more info.

## update

According the last paragraph of [Use Azure Autoscale](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md#use-azure-autoscale):

> When you configure multiple policies and rules, they could conflict with each other. Autoscale uses the following conflict resolution rules to ensure that there is always a sufficient number of instances running:
>
> - Scale out operations always take precedence over scale in operations.
> - When scale out operations conflict, the rule that initiates the largest increase in the number of instances takes precedence.
> - When scale in operations conflict, the rule that initiates the smallest decrease in the number of instances takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks, I've read through this material previously.
The question actually is about — why is Azure scaling against the configuration. In config it is either 2 instances or 20. In reality — other numbers appear.

Comment: It could be the conflict issue of multiple policies and rules.

Comment: Well, I have to rules: one sets to 20 instances, the other one sets to 2 instances. There is no rule, which would add/remove N instances, there are only these two rules. I don't see how could they conflict, so that I'd get, say, 15 instances.

Comment: Could you provide your autoscale setting content? Via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510367.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: Added json from resource explorer. Hope it is what you asked for.

Comment: Hi, it's a little strange, how did you create or configure the autoscale setting? Because there several elements different with the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510367.aspx, and different with my settings in resource explorer. E.G. `MetricSource` vs `metricResourceUri` in yours, and the `type` of `scaleAction`, which is described as `Currently, this must be set to **ChangeCount**.`

Comment: Configured using portal.azure.com. Will add the screenshot of config shortly. BTW, the article you reference is pretty old, also it refers to classic deployments, while we use resource-groups.